# Dynamically add/remove function while calling one single function using parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function called f0 having some parameters. When i call it, it calls some other functions with some parameters(for example the same parameters).
The problem is, can i add somehow these functions dynamically?

A simple solution would be something like this:

```
var callf1=true;
var callf2=true;
var callf3=true;

function f1(params){
//some code
}
function f2(params){
//some other code
}
function f3(params){
//some code
}

function f0(params){
    if(callf1){
      f1();
    }
    if(callf2){
      f1();
    }
    if(callf3){
      f1();
    }

}

function mymain(){
    f0(params);
}

setInterval("mymain()",5000);
```

This option is much time consuming because every time it has to check the variables. Could i use somehow the trigger option in JQuery using runtime and giving parameters?

I would be glad if you can recommend me an easier and simpler solution.

Comment: Why do you need this? It seems you're trying to encode program flow with parameters. Are you trying to implement a state machine?

Comment: Not really. I am trying to call some functions (or a group of function) at a specific time.

For example within the first 5 minutes i want to call the functions f1 and f2, between minutes 3 and 15  to be called the function f3.

I want to process some incoming data, and each function creates like a statistics of the incoming data.

Comment: This pretty much voers this question Calling dynamic function with dynamic parameters in Javascript

Answer (score 0):

The current solution **is not** time consuming since checking some variables once in 5 seconds is far from complicated for the computer. So you probably would want to stick with the current solution - the only thing I would reccomend would be ditching the string-command from setInterval

from:

```
setInterval("mymain()",5000);
```

to:

```
setInterval(mymain,5000);
```

This way you would bypass an `eval` statement which is probably much more time consuming than a variable check would ever be.

Comment: The update is made each second. I did put that 5000 just as an example.
But thanks for the tip.